# how to get user is idle in Joomla 2.5

Tags: php, session, joomla, joomla2.5

I have an issue with Joomla session lifetime. I recently found that Joomla session lifetime is only works for back-end. I have spend more than 10 hours for finding the solution, I didn't find any solution for that how can I get the user is idle for long time and exceed the session lifetime limit gets log-out. If some have any solution or suggestion for that issue, Please help me.

Comment: Can you confirm what session handler you have set in `Global Config > System > Session Settings`?

Comment: It's set for database and time limit is 15 min.

Comment: Are you saying you want the session to automatically flush without a reload?   The way Japplication works is that every time there is a reload it checks a portion of the sessions and deletes the expired ones. It doesn't do them all basically because if you have a big website that becomes a performance killer and you will be getting a lot of reloads anyway if you have a few thousand people on your site at any time.  If you want to force a session to be flushed without the user without a page load you'll need to do a cron job.

Answer (score 0):

In the "Admin" panel,

`Go to "site" > "global configuration" > "system" tab`.

You should see a field called `session lifetime` (which adjusts the session inactivity log out time for users). I believe the default setting is **15 minutes**.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion , I already know that but if you check my question again that I said it's not working for frontside of the website.

Answer (score 0):

```
$user = JFactory::getUser();
if ($user->guest == 1) {
    //User is not logged in or session has timed out.
}
```